# Check if a string contains a set of characters

Tags: performance, ruby, regex

I have written this piece of code to check if a string contains a set of characters, regardless of the order.

Eg: 'ruby is best' / 'bysbe' => true

Code:

```
def find_chars(s1,s2)
s1.chars.sort.join =~ Regexp.new(s2.chars.sort.join(".*")) ? true : false
end
```

I need to optimize it to reduce executing time. How? What is slowing the performance, the regex, the methods, the ternary, or all together?

EDIT:

The last one provided by @Flambino performs significantly better, and this one performs best

```
def find_chars(subject, characters)
  characters.chars.uniq.all?{|i| characters.count(i) <= subject.count(i)} 
end
```

Now I only need to investigate why :)

Comment: Does `s1` have to have every character in `s2` or only some of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regex for this is overkill, but so is sorting both strings. I'd just do:

```
def find_chars(subject, characters)
  characters.chars.all? { |char| subject.include?(char) }
end
```

Just doing a very cursory benchmarking, but it's an order of magnitude faster, at least for small strings like your example.

*Edit:* I should point out that this implementation is different from the original in that it doesn't care about multiples of the same character.

The original code will return false if given, say, `ruby` and `rr`, since there's only one "r" in the string. The implementation above, however, just matches the first letter twice - or N times, if need be.

Whether this is correct for your use-case, I don't know.

Incidentally, you could consider `uniq`ing the character set to avoid redundant matching, but it'll probably be much slower for all but the most extreme input.

*Edit 2:* Responding to comments. This isn't very pretty, but should get the job done:

```
def find_chars(subject, characters)
  letters = characters.chars
  subject.chars.each do |letter|
    i = letters.index(letter)
    next if i.nil?
    letters.delete_at(i)
    return true if letters.empty?
  end
  false
end
```

Unfortunately, something simple like `(characters.chars - subject.chars).empty?` won't work as it too deletes duplicates.

In the above, it doesn't actually matter if you loop through the `subject` and search the `characters`, or vice-versa. However, it might matter performance-wise. I'd suggest looping over the longer string, and searching the shorter one (which'll get shorter the more stuff gets matched and deleted):

```
def find_chars(subject, characters)
  letters, repertoire = [subject, characters].sort_by(&:length)
  repertoire.each do |letter|
    i = letters.index(letter)
    next if i.nil?
    letters.delete_at(i)
    return true if letters.empty?
  end
  false
end
```

Now, I don't know how this fares in terms of performance. You'll have to test it out.

You could also return to sorting the `characters` string, and do binary search; maybe quicker than `index`.

By the way, I'd consider monkey-patching this method into `String`. It'd be nicer to write `"hello".covers?("lelo")` or something. But whether stand-alone or monkey-patched, `find_chars` isn't a great name.

*Edit 3:* The above can also be written as so, though performance is likely similar:

```
def find_chars(subject, characters)
  letters, repertoire = [subject, characters].sort_by(&:length)
  repertoire.each_char do |letter|
    letters.sub!(letter, '')
    return true if letters.empty?
  end
  false
end
```

Just for the heck of it, here's another approach. But I doubt it'll be fast:

```
def find_chars(subject, characters)
  repertoire = subject.chars.group_by { |char| char } # use &:itself for Ruby 2.2+
  letters = characters.chars.group_by { |char| char }

  letters.all? do |char, list|
    repertoire[char] && repertoire[char].count >= list.count
  end
end
```

It's basically frequency analysis and comparison. Again, it might be worth to pick the shortest of the two strings as the one to loop.

Comment: Thanks,  very nice and tidy; I tend to overcomplicate the code… I still have very few tools in my toolbox, and sometimes I forget some of the tools I have.
I'll google about performance in regex and strings operations.

Comment: @LuisF.Vidal no prob. And it's not the strings per se, it's the splitting, sorting, and joining, and more so the regex. The compilation is probably the heaviest part with execution in a close second (for short strings at least). It's a very liberal regex and its greediness probably makes it do a lot of lookaheads. Might be tweaked to be faster, but regex is still overkill

Comment: I've been trying your method, and did not fulfill my needs. I need to check wether I can replicate s2 with characters given in s1. Eg:
`s1 = 'hello' / s2 = 'lelo' => true |
s1 = 'hello' / s2 = 'lelol' => false`

Comment: @LuisF.Vidal Ah, I see. I'll see if I can come up with a better solution. In the meantime, you can remove the checkmark, if you like

Comment: @LuisF.Vidal Updated my answer

Comment: Your code works fine, but it's performance still exceeds the execution time I need to achieve, it's very close to the performance of my first code. I will try other approaches, and comment here if I find a faster way to get the job done.

I agree find_chars is not a great name, and it needs to be monkey-patched; but for now I'll worry about performance only, and deal with refactoring later on. 

Thanks the help, you have opened some new ways to approach the problem.

Comment: @LuisF.Vidal Welp, too bad. I've added a couple more alternatives, but I doubt they'll make an impact. Feel free to try them out though

Comment: actually that last code passes the performance test!! Thanks you very much, I will now try to find out why it performs better than the others. Thanks!

Comment: @LuisF.Vidal Interesting. Hashes are fast, but I didn't think they'd be fast enough compared to the other solutions. Cool.

Comment: And with some of the insights and perspective gained, I also came up with the code I added in Edit
Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has [sets](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html):

```
require 'set'

def find_chars(string, characters)
  characters.chars.to_set.subset?(string.chars.to_set)
end
```